# Why is graft-vs-host so selective against phylogenetically close cells?

Tags: immune-system

Is there a well established explanation for the phenomena that graft-vs-host is so much more selective against phylogenetically close cells? See historically significant references below,

*"This type of aggression of the immune system is thus particularly directed against allo-antigens and is much less in evidence across two animals species. “ - Jerne, 1971*

*"Normal lymphoid cells obtained from animals that are phylogenetically unrelated or only distantly related to the chicken do not initiate graft versus host reactions when introduced into chicken embryos. " - Lafferty, 1968*

#### References

Lafferty, K., & Jones, M. (1969). REACTIONS OF THE GRAFT VERSUS HOST (GVH) TYPE. Australian Journal of Experimental Biology and Medical Science, 47(1), 17–54. https://doi.org/10.1038/icb.1969.3

Jerne, N. K. (1971). The somatic generation of immune recognition. European Journal of Immunology, 1(1), 1–9. https://doi.org/10.1002/eji.1830010102

Answer (score 1):

Since this has gone unanswered, I'll give my best guess. My guess is that closely related MHC* can still be recognized by CD4/CD8 (while not in distant relatives phylogenetically), but, the MHC + eventual bound peptide will not be recognized as self (with or without bound peptide), since its structure may differ even when binding self-antigen peptides that were exposed to T-cells during central tolerance "traning".

I am very intersted in what the established explanation is including references, and invite better answers if there is competence to produce that.

**in the context of the question, i.e., at species level, within species sufficiently close MHC genes are not attacked at all and compatible.*

I'll attach potential reference to my guess that ability to recognize MHC as... MHC, decreases with phylogenetic distance,

Vignali, D. A., Moreno, J., Schiller, D., & Hämmerling, G. J. (1992). Species-specific binding of CD4 to the beta 2 domain of major histocompatibility complex class II molecules. Journal of Experimental Medicine, 175(4), 925–932. https://doi.org/10.1084/jem.175.4.925

that references this,

Lamarre, D., Ashkenazi, A., Fleury, S., Smith, D., Sekaly, R., & Capon, D. (1989). The MHC-binding and gp120-binding functions of CD4 are separable. Science, 245(4919), 743–746. https://doi.org/10.1126/science.2549633

that says this,

> *"although human and mouse CD4 share a high degree of amino acid sequence identity (19), the murine homolog does not bind gpl20 (11) and does not interact with the human class II MHC molecule HLA-DP as assessed by functional and adhesion assays (20). "*